# ActiveRecord mapping selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I have an `Order` that has many `Bids`

if I were to do `order.bids` I would get back an array of two `bid` objects.  Each one of these `bid objects has a boolean field called accpeted`.  How would I return back only the accepted bid?

something like `order.bids.accepted?`

I figured I would put this in the `Bid` model, but cant seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Rails [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :accepted, -> { where(accepted: true) }
end
```

After that you can access the accepted bids using:

```
order.bids.accepted
```

*(and there should be no question mark at the end.)*

Comment: duuuh scopes are the way to go!